# Flashing the result even of system pause C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6

Here is my code ... I want to stop it on the result, but result is showing after pressing a key ... It is flashing the result after pressing the key ... I'm using Microsoft Visual C++6.0 and windows 7.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    int a, b, n;
    int danni[6][25];

    cout << "n= ";
    cin >> n;

    for (a = 0; a < n; a++) {
        for (b = 0; b < n; b++) {
            cout << "danni[" << a << "][" << b << "]= ";
            cin >> danni[a][b];
        }
    }

    for (a = 0; a < n; a++) {
        cout << "\n ";

        for (b = 0; b < n; b++) {
            //cout<<danni[a][b]<<" ";
            cout << "Fak nomer: " << a << b;
        }

        cout << "Spec: " << a << b;
        cout << "Grupa: ";
        cout << a << b;
        cout << "Sreden uspeh: " << a << b;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You will need to share a little more about your development environment and OS in order for anyone to suggest useful solutions to this problem.

Comment: windows 7 + Microsoft visual c++ 6.0 (edited up)

Comment: WTF is anyone still doing using VC6?  You're aware that's like over 10 years out of date, right?  And was buggy as hell even when it was current?

Comment: can you format your code better, please?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't crash?

Comment: Your code lacks meaningful indentation. Please fix it to avoid permanently ruining my power of sight. Unless you were going for obscure ASCII art, which is the only exception...

Comment: If the stop is for debugging purposes, use a breakpoint instead of `system("pause")`.

Comment: actually the program is not ended ... (it maybe doing a bulls**ts ... but it works ... i see some kinds of result when press a key ...) I tried to use getche(); with <conio.h> but ... same problem ...

Comment: I don't really understand why you'd write code that looks like this even from the very start. You don't have to have finished writing your program in order to have written it without bashing your nose on the space bar every few seconds.

Comment: I took a shot at re-indenting your code, but take care: IIRC, if you have a `for` loop with no brackets, only the next statement will occur within the `for` loop, even if there are more statements on that line.

Comment: @cHao Unfortunately many "education institutions" haven't quite arrived in the 21st century yet.

To the original poster: This is not C++. Please file a request to get your teacher vocational training and suspension from teaching until the completion of it.

Comment: @cHao Unfortunately some "companies" haven't quite arrived in the 21st century yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `cout.flush();` before system pause. Another option would be to add and `cout << endl`(as it hiddenly flushes the stream).

Answer (score 0):

Streams perform buffering. That means that they don't always write to the console as soon as you ask them to, but wait a bit more input so that they can do it in chunks and save some resources.

In this case, though, you want the stream to be totally flushed before the pause.

Write any of the following to do so:

```
std::cout.flush();
std::cout << std::flush;
```